# ColdFusion Read Mobile Device File and Write Mobile Device File - From Local Device

Tags: android, mobile, coldfusion, apk, cffile

I am trying to read a file that is stored locally on a mobile device.
I'm having trouble knowing where to store it. Read/Write it from.
Should the file be right with the config.xml or stored in the www area on device.

Ultimately the web app is being all served from webpages.  But I want to store their login information to do auto logins really.

So read the file : logset.txt

I want to read it by and do a cflocation for auto login:

```
<cfset fc = #fileRead(expandPath("/logset.txt"), "utf-8")#>
```

Then if no login settings.  Present them a form and write the file, then cflocation to login.

```
<cfset fpath = expandpath('\')>

<CFFILE ACTION="Write"
  FILE="#FPath#logset.txt"
  nameConflict="overwrite"
  OUTPUT="#nf#">
```

This all works on the web.  But I need it to write the local file to the device and read it from the device.  Path issue is what I need sorted I guess.

Comment: You will need to use cookies for this.

Comment: Never store login credentials! Use cookies to store some login token as Dan recommended. And remember, ColdFusion runs on the server so it cannot write a file to a mobile device.

Comment: So use the cookie instead of the session variable?  If they lose connection? Change wifi/mobile - will it retain the cookie information?